# Logic App gives error when updating CRM field

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, dynamics-crm-2011, crm, azure-logic-apps, power-automate

I am trying to push some data into CRM utilizing the logic app and the parameter fields.
Some of the fields get pushed through, while others do not. I am trying to understand what is the logic behind this?

All of the fields go through except the LeadPM field. I get this error:
"message": "Syntax error: character '"' is not valid at position 1 in '("Yu li")'."

This is what I have done so far:

[image]

When I got this error, I added "" and this did not work, so then I added '' and this did not work either. I finally did not add any quotes and am still getting this error. Any insight on this would be greatly appreciated.

JSON PARSE

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems the value of your `FeaturePM` is `"` and it can't be stored in `Lead PM` directly. You need to add a `\` to escape it. Change the value of `FeaturePM` to `\"` and then put it into `Lead PM`.

Comment: Let me try this

Comment: This is what I did, and it did not work:      "\DynamicFeaturePM\"   Is this correct? I put in the dynamic FeaturePM field between the "\ \"

Comment: I am changing this to "\FeaturePM\" within the actual    "Create Record" Action. Is this correct? Or does the "\FeaturePM\" need to go in the JSON parse?

Comment: Hi @Lynnette I'm not so clear about the details of your logic app, but in my opinion you should put the dynamic FeaturePM field between the \" \" but not between "\ \"

Comment: @Lynnette If it still doesn't work, please share a screenshot of the original data which you do the Parse JSON.

Comment: Ok I did this:  \"FeaturePM"\ and this did not work

Comment: @Lynnette No, not \"FeaturePM"\, it should be \"FeaturePM\"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219164/discussion-between-hury-shen-and-lynnette).

Comment: Hi @Lynnette I find some information in another post, it says the value should be a guid. Could you please put a hard code ab8cd101-1234-e123-80e3-c5636baace8c into "Lead PM" box for a test.

Comment: Ok I will try this in the morning. I wonder how they find the ‘hard code’ could you send me this source?? - Thank you tremendously and I will upvote if this works!!

Comment: And just add the hard code within parentheses? “  “

Comment: @Lynnette No, only the hardcode `ab8cd101-1234-e123-80e3-c5636baace8c`  without parentheses or " ". The hardcode `ab8cd101-1234-e123-80e3-c5636baace8c` is a guid which I random made up(because guid is in format `xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx`). I'm not sure if it will work.

Comment: Oh . Can you send me the link to the post or source you read? I’ll try this is the morning . Thank you!

Comment: This [post](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Power-Automate/Automatically-create-record-in-Dynamics-365-CRM-from-GP/td-p/43828). Maybe you have already seen this post.

Comment: Ok no I have not seen this yet. This is very helpful